# Escape doesn't work

Tags: macos, keyboard

OS: OSX Snow Leopard 10.6.7
After a several months of work escape key stopped working. But it works with the Command, Option and Control keys (checked with 'Keyboard View').
Restarted finder with moving com.apple.finder.plist and com.apple.systemprefernces.plist.

How to fix it?

Comment: Why do you need the esc-key for?

Comment: @Michiel I simply couldn't switch states between *INSERT*, *VISUAL*, *NORMAL* in **vim** via **Terminal.app**

Comment: good for you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by removing [box.net](http://box.net/) application, it somehow shadowed escape key...